# Angular 2 Model-Driven form.reset() doesn't reset FormArray property

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have an angular 2 model driven form that has a property of type `FormArray`.  When I call the `myForm.reset(this._originalValue)` method, the number of items in the `FormArray` is not reset to the original value.

Here is a plunker showing the problem:  https://plnkr.co/edit/gRHD5Ikbm1aGzFQUF2nn?p=preview

Is there a way to force the `myForm.reset()` method to reset the count of items in properties of type `FormArray`?  Or do I have to manually reset it?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852183/angular-2-remove-all-items-from-a-formarray

Answer (score 5):

Well, it appears this is a known issue and the Angular team has decided that folks will have to manually reset the FormArray size.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10960