# Remove all items from a FormArray in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form array inside a FormBuilder and I am dynamically changing forms, i.e. on click load data from application 1 etc.

The issue I am having is that all the data loads in but the data in the FormArray stays and just concats the old items with new.

How do I clear that FormArray to only have the new items.

I've tried this

```ts
const control2 = <FormArray>this.registerForm.controls['other_Partners'];
control2.setValue([]);
```

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    if (params['id']) {
      this.id = Number.parseInt(params['id']);
    } else { this.id = null;}
  });
  if (this.id != null && this.id != NaN) {
    alert(this.id);
    this.editApplication();
    this.getApplication(this.id);
  } else {
    this.newApplication();
  }
}

onSelect(Editedapplication: Application) {
  this.router.navigate(['/apply', Editedapplication.id]);
}

editApplication() {
  this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: null,
    type_of_proposal: ['', Validators.required],
    title: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    lead_teaching_fellow: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    status: '',
    userID: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).username,
    contactEmail: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).email,
    forename: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).firstname,
    surname: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).surname,
    line_manager_discussion: true,
    document_url: '',
    keywords: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    financial_Details: this.formBuilder.group({
      id: null,
      buying_expertise_description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      buying_expertise_cost: ['', [Validators.required]],
      buying_out_teaching_fellow_cost: ['', [Validators.required]],
      buying_out_teaching_fellow_desc: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      travel_desc: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      travel_cost: ['', [Validators.required]],
      conference_details_desc: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      conference_details_cost: ['', [Validators.required]],
    }),

    partners: this.formBuilder.array([
        //this.initEditPartner(),
        //this.initEditPartner()
        // this.initMultiplePartners(1)
      ]
    ),
    other_Partners: this.formBuilder.array([
      //this.initEditOther_Partners(),
    ])
  });
}

getApplication(id) {
  this.applicationService.getAppById(id, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).username)
    .subscribe(Response => {
      if (Response.json() == false) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      } else {
        this.application = Response.json();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.application.partners.length;i++) {
          this.addPartner();
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < this.application.other_Partners.length; i++) {
          this.addOther_Partner();
        }

        this.getDisabledStatus(Response.json().status);
        (<FormGroup>this.registerForm) .setValue(Response.json(), { onlySelf: true });
      }
    });
}
```

ngOnInit is not being called on click

Comment: A related issue [is tracked here on the Angular repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18531)

Answer (score 201, accepted):

I had same problem. There are two ways to solve this issue.

#### Preserve subscription

You can manually clear each FormArray element by calling the `removeAt(i)` function in a loop.

```
clearFormArray = (formArray: FormArray) => {
  while (formArray.length !== 0) {
    formArray.removeAt(0)
  }
}
```

> The advantage to this approach is that any subscriptions on your `formArray`, such as that registered with `formArray.valueChanges`, will not be lost.

See the [FormArray documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html) for more information.

---

#### Cleaner method (but breaks subscription references)

You can replace whole FormArray with a new one.

```
clearFormArray = (formArray: FormArray) => {
  formArray = this.formBuilder.array([]);
}
```

> This approach causes an issue if you're subscribed to the `formArray.valueChanges` observable! If you replace the FromArray with a new array, you will lose the reference to the observable that you're subscribed to.

Comment: As of Angular 8+ the preferred way of removing all components from a FormArray is using `formArray.clear();`

Comment: Also, yourFormArray.setValue([])); and    yourFormGroup.setControl('yourFormArray', []);

Comment: bye bye validation with this approach

Comment: @Renan I'm using formControl

Answer (score 51):

As of Angular 8+ you can use `clear()` to remove all controls in the FormArray:

```
const arr = new FormArray([
   new FormControl(),
   new FormControl()
]);
console.log(arr.length);  // 2

arr.clear();
console.log(arr.length);  // 0
```

For previous versions the recommended way is:

```
while (arr.length) {
   arr.removeAt(0);
}
```

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#clear

Comment: This is still working in Angular 13

Answer (score 39):

Or you can simply clear the controls

```
this.myForm= {
     name: new FormControl(""),
     desc: new FormControl(""),
     arr: new FormArray([])
}
```

Add something `array`

```
const arr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.arr;
arr.push(new FormControl("X"));
```

Clear the array

```
const arr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.arr;
arr.controls = [];
```

When you have multiple choices selected and clear, sometimes it doesn't update the view. A workaround is to add

```
arr.removeAt(0)
```

#### UPDATE

A more elegant solution to use form arrays is using a getter at the top of your class and then you can access it.

```
get inFormArray(): FormArray {
    this.myForm.get('inFormArray') as FormArray;
}
```

And to use it in a template

```
<div *ngFor="let c of inFormArray; let i = index;" [formGroup]="i">
other tags...
</div>
```

Reset:

```
inFormArray.reset();
```

Push:

```
inFormArray.push(new FormGroup({}));
```

Remove value at index: 1

```
inFormArray.removeAt(1);
```

#### UPDATE 2:

Get partial object, get all errors as JSON and many other features, use the [NaoFormsModule](https://naologic.github.io/alexandria/#/forms)

Comment: The "arr.controls = [ ];" mention is really great!

Comment: @Pian, Only const arr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.arr;
arr.controls = []; is working to clear form array. TQ

Comment: `inFormArray.at(1).remove();`  gives me a `[ts] Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.` transpiler error.

Comment: @Pian0_M4n in your template, `let c of inFormArray` should be `let c of inFormArray.controls` ?

Answer (score 35):

**Angular 8**

simply use `clear()` method on formArrays :

```
(this.invoiceForm.controls['other_Partners'] as FormArray).clear();
```

Comment: simple and clear answer. great!!!!!. thanks

Answer (score 18):

Simply

```
formArray.clear()
```

would be enough

Comment: This is should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 11):

Warning!

The Angular v6.1.7 [FormArray documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#adding-or-removing-controls-from-a-form-array) says:

> To change the controls in the array, use the push, insert, or removeAt
>   methods in FormArray itself. These methods ensure the controls are
>   properly tracked in the form's hierarchy. Do not modify the array of
>   AbstractControls used to instantiate the FormArray directly, as that
>   result in strange and unexpected behavior such as broken change
>   detection.

Keep this in mind if you are using the `splice` function directly on the `controls` array as one of the answer suggested.

Use the `removeAt` function.

```
  while (formArray.length !== 0) {
    formArray.removeAt(0)
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

Angular v4.4 if you need to save the same reference to the instance of FormArray try this:

```
purgeForm(form: FormArray) {
  while (0 !== form.length) {
    form.removeAt(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good way to preserve the subscription while popping elements out of the array.

Comment: @mtpultz please note the changelog (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41856927/revisions) of the accepted answer. In time when I left this answer accepted answer was different from current.

Answer (score 8):

```
(this.questionForm.controls['answers'] as FormArray).clear();
```

Comment: that would be enough

Answer (score 7):

You can easily define a getter for your array and clear it as follows:

```
  formGroup: FormGroup    
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      sliders: this.fb.array([])
    })
  }
  get sliderForms() {
    return this.formGroup.get('sliders') as FormArray
  }

  clearAll() {
    this.formGroup.reset()
    this.sliderForms.clear()
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Use FormArray.clear() to remove all the elements of an array in a FormArray

Answer (score 6):

Since Angular 8 you can use `this.formArray.clear()` to clear all values in form array.
It's a simpler and more efficient alternative to removing all elements one by one

Answer (score 5):

Update: Angular 8 finally got method to clear the Array
FormArray.clear()

Answer (score 4):

I never tried using formArray, I have always worked with FormGroup, and you can remove all controls using:

```
Object.keys(this.formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
          this.formGroup.removeControl(key);
        });
```

being formGroup an instance of FormGroup.

Answer (score 3):

Provided the data structure for what you will be replacing the information in the array with matches what is already there you can use `patchValue`

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html#!#reset-anchor

> patchValue(value: any[], {onlySelf, emitEvent}?: {onlySelf?: boolean,
>   emitEvent?: boolean}) : void Patches the value of the FormArray. It
>   accepts an array that matches the structure of the control, and will
>   do its best to match the values to the correct controls in the group.
>
> It accepts both super-sets and sub-sets of the array without throwing
>   an error.

```
const arr = new FormArray([
   new FormControl(),
   new FormControl()
]);
console.log(arr.value);   // [null, null]
arr.patchValue(['Nancy']);
console.log(arr.value);   // ['Nancy', null]
```

Alternatively you could use `reset`

> reset(value?: any, {onlySelf, emitEvent}?: {onlySelf?: boolean,
>   emitEvent?: boolean}) : void Resets the FormArray. This means by
>   default:
>
> The array and all descendants are marked pristine The array and all
>   descendants are marked untouched The value of all descendants will be
>   null or null maps You can also reset to a specific form state by
>   passing in an array of states that matches the structure of the
>   control. The state can be a standalone value or a form state object
>   with both a value and a disabled status.

```
this.arr.reset(['name', 'last name']);
console.log(this.arr.value);  // ['name', 'last name']
```

> OR

```
this.arr.reset([   {value: 'name', disabled: true},   'last' ]);
console.log(this.arr.value);  // ['name', 'last name']
console.log(this.arr.get(0).status);  // 'DISABLED'
```

[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/yLDrmU7kPBCdNt0wePrT?p=preview) a forked Plunker demo from some earlier work of mine demoing a very simple utilization of each.

Comment: surely this means you must have the exact same number of items in the array?

Answer (score 2):

To keep the code clean I have created the following extension method for anyone using Angular 7 and below. This can also be used to extend any other functionality of Reactive Forms.

```
import { FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

declare module '@angular/forms/src/model' {
  interface FormArray {
    clearArray: () => FormArray;
  }
}

FormArray.prototype.clearArray = function () {
  const _self = this as FormArray;
  _self.controls = [];
  _self.setValue([]);
  _self.updateValueAndValidity();
  return _self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am very late but I found some other way where you don't need to have loops. you can reset array by setting array control to empty.

Below code will reset your array.

`this.form.setControl('name', this.fb.array([]))`

Answer (score 0):

While loop will take long time to delete all items if array has 100's of items. You can empty both controls and value properties of FormArray like below.

clearFormArray = (formArray: FormArray) => { formArray.controls = []; formArray.setValue([]); }

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 7 or a previous version and you dont' have access to the clear() method, there is a way to achieve that without doing any loop:

```
yourFormGroup.controls.youFormArrayName = new FormArray([]);
```