# Angular - Remove the last array I add on my form group

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

On my **NgOnInit()** I´m creating a new form like this.

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.expenseForm = this.fb.group({
      type: '',
      expenses: this.fb.array([this.buildExpense()])
    })
  }
```

I have a **key** called **type** that starts empty on my object and a key called **expenses**

these **expenses key** receive an array every time the user clicks a button.

```
  buildExpense(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      description: '',
      quantity: '',
      price: ''
    })
  }

  addExpense(): void {
    this.expenses.push(this.buildExpense())
  }
```

Html

```
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary add" type="button" (click)="addExpense()">Add Expense</button>
```

My objective is to remove the last array add on my form group

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852183/angular-2-remove-all-items-from-a-formarray
**Beware**
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#adding-or-removing-controls-from-a-form-array
*Adding or removing controls from a form array
To change the controls in the array, use the push, insert, removeAt or clear methods in FormArray itself. These methods ensure the controls are properly tracked in the form's hierarchy. Do not modify the array of AbstractControls used to instantiate the FormArray directly, as that result in strange and unexpected behavior such as broken change detection.*

Comment: @AndrewAllen Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think  you  want to   remove  the last element of the formArray expenses. To first create the get()  for expenses as follows

```
get expenses(): FormArray {
    return this.expenseForm.get('expenses') as FormArray;
  }
```

Then to remove the last element from formArray expenses

```
deleteExpense()
{
  if(this.expenses.length > 0)
  this.expenses.removeAt(this.expenses.length-1);
}
```

Comment: Paul !! Thank you very much !! I understand :)

Answer (score 1):

As per my undestanding from the question you want to remove the last array , so use the pop method
 say if there is delete method:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary add" type="button" (click)="deleteExpense()">Delete Expense</button>
```

SO we can create a method

```
     deleteExpense() : void {
    let index = this.expenses.length-1;
 if(index){
        (this. expenseForm.get(
          'expenses'
        ) as FormArray).removeAt(index);
      }
}
```